# StringReverse question

Tags: string-manipulation, random

I was thinking about how to make this with the StringReverse, but I failed:

I have a sequence of (for example) "FDSRTYNHFNKHLIUHG", I wish to reverse, but randomly long sequence reversed from a random place of the character, for example FDSRTYNHFNKHLIHUG (UH-HU), but can be FDSFHNYTRNKHLIUHG (RTYNHF-FHNYTR). Do you have some good idea? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
randomStringReverse[s_String] := 
  StringReplacePart[s, StringReverse @ StringTake[s, #], #]& @ 
    Sort @ RandomInteger[{1, StringLength @ s}, 2]

str = "FDSRTYNHFNKHLIUHG";
newStr = randomStringReverse[str]
(* "FDSRTYNHILHKNFUHG" *)
```

And to check:

```
MapAt[
  Reverse, 
  Transpose @ DeleteCases[Characters /@ {str, newStr} // Transpose, {a_, a_}], 
  1
]
(* {{"I", "L", "H", "K", "N", "F"}, {"I", "L", "H", "K", "N", "F"}} *)
```